# Android App starts with two activities caused by Manifest and app.Application

Tags: java, android

I want my app to start via the `android.app.Application` class, but my IDE tells me that I can't compile the app if the `manifest.xml` doesn't have a default activity.

When I currently start my app, two activities are started. One from the `android.app.Application` and the other from the `manifest.xml`.

If I select the MainActivity as default in my manifest, then it starts the MainActitivity two times. So this isn't a solution.

How to fix it, so that the MainActitivy only starts via the `android.app.Application` class?

**manifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name="myapp.SecondActivity"">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Application class**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initAppConfig();
        startActivity();
    }

    ...

    private void startActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you want to start the app from the Application class? Android has a mechanism that does this for you

Comment: Workaround for this : add launch mode Singletask in manifest. But is there any specific requirement for this. Why launching activity in application class

Comment: Apps are launched mainly by starting an `Activity`. The `Application` running is rather a kind of side effect. It will run whenever a component in the app is launched, but you can't launch an app by just starting the `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at  `android:name="myapp.SecondActivity"` Remove the extra " .

```
<activity
        android:name="myapp.SecondActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: check the answer now